# Can't download image from eucalyptus cloud

Tags: eucalyptus

I'm newbie in using eucalyptus. I need to download modify a prepackaged image. I use command

```
euca-download-bundle
```

to download it. It has a required parameter - bucket.

I want to download this image. 
mi-E07C107C
image-store-1297468153/image.manifest.xml
eki-F6BE10FF
eri-0B3C116B
but I always get error -

> Unable to get bucket

Here are the commands I tried:

euca-download-bundle -b image-store-1297468153

euca$ euca-download-bundle -b /var/lib/eucalyptus/bukkits/image-store-1297468153

Answer (score 0):

you may not be able to download the bundle if you are not the same user who uploaded it. For example, if admin uploaded that bundle, but the user aleksey is the one trying to download it, that would be the error you get.